# SSH showing "connection failed" after installing "pip"

Tags: python, ssh, raspbian-stretch, python-2.x, raspbian-lite

Python3, pip3 and python was installed before on my Raspberry Pi. Today I've successfully installed pip using below command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

After few hours later I'm not able to connect my Raspberry Pi with SSH. I have many important data in the SD card.
How can I fix it or at least save all my data?

**Update:** Not even SFTP is working.

Answer (score 0):

To save your data you can put the SD Card into a card reader attached to a computer that is able to read an `ext4` file system. All computer with a linux operating system can do that. Then mount the second partition on the SD Card and copy all your data to a save place.